# Variational Autoencoder - WARNING:tensorflow: Gradients do not exist for variables [] when minimizing the loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a **Variational Autoencoder**, using the last part of the official [keras page](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), the input it's the mnist dataset normalized and flat:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
```

The model:

```
original_dim = 28 * 28
intermediate_dim = 64
latent_dim = 2

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(original_dim,))
h = layers.Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(inputs)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_log_sigma = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(h)

from keras import backend as K

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim),
                              mean=0., stddev=0.1)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon

z = layers.Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])

# Create encoder
encoder = keras.Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')

# Create decoder
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = layers.Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')


reconstruction_loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(inputs, outputs)
reconstruction_loss *= original_dim
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')

vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
        epochs=100,
        batch_size=32,
        validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

But when i train the model i obtain **this warning 4 times** at the first epoch, then the train goes on apparently without problems.

```
Epoch 1/100
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.
2021-02-03 00:03:40.37: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 536.7903 - val_loss: 534.6534
Epoch 2/100
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 533.1923 - val_loss: 532.5651
Epoch 3/100
....
```

My **question** is why are there those warnings, is this a problem and how can i solve it? Because i think that model needs those gradients to improve.

I try to copy this on colab and these warnings do not appear, I don't know if it's because they are automatically hidden in the settings (maybe is cause_error = False).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fact that does not recognise gradients for the decoder layers (dense_layer_4, etc.), suggests that the problem is with the reconstruction loss. In other words, it is recognising gradients for the encoder from the KL loss, and that is why it runs at all. I would say use the vae to get the outputs, such as:

```
vae = keras.Model(inputs, [coding_means, codings_log_var, outputs], name='vae_mlp')
coding_means, codings_log_var, outputs = vae(x_train)
```

From this example, it is also odd to me adding the reconstruction loss like that. I would trying substituting

```
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

for

```
vae.add_loss(K.mean(kl_loss))
vae.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
```